# Simple way to any checkbox cheked or any inputbox filled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem.

I have several checkboxes and several inputboxes on my page.

And they are used as a filter in a catalog and everything is working.

But when I click on a product and I go to the detail page and then back in all browsers it shows the correct selected things again but in Chrome it shows the default page even though the checkboxes are correct.

So, I want to run a function with my code that is responsible for filtering the results on the list page every time when there is at least one checkbox checked or at least one letter or digit written in the inputbox.

Is there any universal way how to any checkobox-checked-and-any-input-filled condition in javascript or jQuery?

something like:

```
if ( $("anycheckbox:checked") OR $("anyinputbox:filled") ) {
    // do my filtr code
} else {
    // do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("checkbox").prop("checked")` should return `true` or `false` based on the state of the element.

For multiple checkboxes, if they all have same class, then just use,

```
$(".className").prop("checked");
```

For input boxes also you can try and attach same class and check if the input is empty or not.

```
!$(".className").val();
```

The above statement should return true or false. Make manipulations based on this.

Comment: thanks, but Ï have many checkboxes and many inputboxes on the page. Is there any simplified soution for that? Or does your solution work like that? What about inputboxes? How would you do that in an if else statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` to check if they are checked and have value

```
$('input').filter(function(){
    return this.checked || !!this.value && this.type !="checkbox";
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/D4ASL/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Demo [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sethuramanP/TA2k7/1/)

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var isFilter=false;
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
    if($(this).prop("checked"))
        isFilter=true;
    });
$('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
    if($.trim($(this).val()).length)
        isFilter=true;
    });
if(isFilter)
{
  //Filter Code
}
}
});
```

In demo am using click event for checking purpose

Answer (score 0):

> You can check at following jsfiddle for check for checkbox checked..
>
> jsfiddle.net/QkEv2/